# How to overcome TS2589 on Enumerate type with dynamic Enumerator (upper limit quantifier number) in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Looking at [Is it possible to restrict number to a certain range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494689/is-it-possible-to-restrict-number-to-a-certain-range) I found the type for creating Ranges and Enumerates.

Looking at [What is the type of an enum in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158272/what-is-the-type-of-an-enum-in-typescript) I found a type definition for passing Enums as values to functions.

Now:
I'm writing a lil UI/UX library [here at prudencss@github](https://github.com/prudencss/react-fp), my hobby project.
Whilst doing so, playing around and trying to do things properly ...
I was trying to introduce the following mechanism:

I wanted to create enums like:

```js
export enum EInputInteractionState {
  Default = 0,
  Hover = 1,
  Focus = 2,
  Active = 4,
  Selected = 8,
}
```

Now, it would be possible and sometimes useful to have combinatoric states of the defined states as well, for example some list element could be:

- hovered
- selected
  at the same time.
  In order to be able to save all that data in one var/number, I define the initial keys/values as
  `v = 0, 2^n ... (== 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...)`
  This would allow me to save every permutated combinatoric state as a number that is the sum of it's active defined states ... that number would always fill the gaps in between the quadratic row of numbers ....
  So basically though I define 5 states (= default state, plus 4 combinatoric states) in EInputInteractionState and define them as `v = 0, 2^n`, the overall combinatorically possible values would be the row symbolising the gaussian sum of `v = 0, 1, 2, 3, ... n, ... (n * 2 - 1)` = (n * (n + 1) /2)`.

Using the knowledge so far I do:

```js
export const gaussianSum = <T extends Enum<T>>(E: T): number => {
  let length = Object.keys(E).filter(v => isNaN(v as unknown)).length;

  return length * (length + 1) / 2 + 1;
}
```

Now I wanted to finally and simply put a Prop into my React Components IProps of:

```
const permutationCount: number = gaussianSum(EInputInteractionState);

interface IProps {
  icon?: TIcon | TIcon[]
  state?: Enumerate<typeof permutationCount>,
}
```

However, if I simply put a concrete number the Enumarte type works quite well, but using this scenario I get TS2589 "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."

Is there a way to solve this issue???

Edit:
typescript playground here:
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThSA7AJgOQgD2GgrgWwB4BBKLYCVAZymLjgEMRDckBrJAewHckA%20PlAC8tANoByADaUA5sAAW4gLplslFDQCWSAGYQ4UACpQA-FAAU54AC4jAGigA6Zw1vEAlMMEA3TppSe5Oo0ls6OmLbaegYAGp5CPn4BplAxULZIEN766VCZ2XAA3ABQxaCQUACiSAT6DBQAkkgUcEgMkiSqFNS09Ews7Fy8fA5oXcF5BABG%20oIiAN5QAAxuDgCMttW1jI3N%20m0d8IjqGNh4RMQjUGiCAL6iY0E9xBLSSHKKKmZLuWtKJWVwNAtvg6hRCI81D0avgZnA5lUYWCIE0WgdCKIlKNBE8NBYojlKu5MSlKrl8voAeVoAAlBjvCCEABiNIA8gBZcbQ6b6ByGVlcvEwuEIyqYADGklwKEZIORhH5VzlO0ZLI5AipQMRBEIlQRNIg4s4cBQhDYEBAnB0VQcwpyAB8oFRgHBtDJBAAyKCLURsDI8uBKWzO13vKC3AFYMDG4BQI1IZ1QGQMXBUKiaekAZQIwigCsFNBBCoE5kqtkM7n9sJyCW9xSgUGksbeH1zrKmACtDcBHOaQFRS%205HC2FACGwhgLhWo3ZAooAAqCwj%20RQADUUDWngA9FAAExrjclW6lSg5ypNMC4YCouri4CaThITPAerQeb1qAAEQgOhTkljIhLHYH4ABKcAUuZrMBDZMpw4qprmu7QbQd6aNkuYACzIZmEDSHeEAoLmAAcwHHsU2gtL%204rQA08CcGANDvg2DbOq%20JibEiKqEERgjMcUZHxomkBwPgV71A%20Ca5smqbplmBClheV43owqGPs%20r7uACFH6FRNGfiAbT4Jo4p0QxdbMU6L4UOx2qglx1JWlAwmiVZElUCM-FAA)

Comment: Why are you passing `EInputInteractionState` as the argument to your function? Your code is missing some types so I can't get it working in a sandbox. Please post a minimum working example to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: At any rate, while I understand how your proposed combinatoric state calculation is intended to work, I can't figure out WHY you would do such a thing. Seems unnecessarily abstract and overkill, unless your entire point is to play around with such a system, consider a different approach.

Comment: I've added the playground in an edit @jered :)

Comment: Your problem is in `EnumerateInternal` type. You should wrap your recursion in some condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, you can start with updating your `EnumerateInternal` type:

```js
type EnumerateInternal<A extends Array<unknown>, N extends number> = N extends A['length'] ? A : EnumerateInternal<PrependNextNum<A>, N>
```

But it might be not the case.

Your `Enumerate` type util should accept only literal numbers.

For instance, if you write:

```js
type Result = Enumerate<10>
```

It would work.

It would work also for `Enumerate<43>`, but nor for `44`.

But why only to 43?

Because it will produce numbers from 0 to 42 (meaning of the life)

So TS has some recursion limit.

If you want use return type of function, you should not write:

```js
Enumerate<typeof gaussianSum>
```

Instead, you should write:

```js
Enumerate<ReturnType<typeof gaussianSum>>
```

P.S. It is much safer to use `Number.isNaN` instead of `isNaN`

Comment: First: thx for the Number.isNaN hint!!!
Second: nice joke! haha
Main: Thx for the hint of Typescript having that recursion limit.
I'm gonna wait if somebody comes up with something before I mark this answer as accepted :)
Be aware, I'm not the TS Guru who wrote those type definitions, they are from the stackoverflow-questions mentioned at the beginning of the question.
I guess I'm stuck on my own :)

Comment: @Joehannes sure, no problem )) Maybe smbd comes up with better explanation and solution. Will be happy to read it either